# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges Does not working

Tags: ios, swift3, location, core-location, background-fetch

I am making an application that uses the device's location service. This service needs to capture the postition everytime there is a change in location and it should keep running in all situations (background / foreground / killed), so I'm using the *startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()* method, but when I send it to the background, it Works for some short time and then it stops, after that It doens´t capture any position. I get moving the distance that the documentation suggests to get an position update (500m)  and nothing happens. What could I be doing wrong? Note: On simulator it works perfectly, however on physical device it does not work.

The ***Info.plist*** file has the background setting enabled

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
  </array>
```

***AppDelegate.swift***

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = ViewController()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.other
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    return true
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = ViewController()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.other
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}
```

***ViewController.swift***

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {    
    // Capture of new location 
}
```

Comment: How are you identifying the location change? are you sending any local notification to yourself?

Comment: `didEnterBackground` is too late to enable location updates. If you do it there you will only receive updates for a limited time. Try enabling significant location change settings while your app is still in the foreground.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina print on the screen the location when it changes

Comment: How are you checking practically. Are you changing location from GPX file or you are going outside and checking?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I'm going outside and checking

Comment: @Paulw11 where should I do enable the significant location changes? In the applicationWillResignActive ?

Comment: Just do it when your app launches

Comment: @Paulw11 but I need, that communicates all the time, same when de app are killed, that is way I call inside `didEnterBackground`

Comment: Start it when your app launches and never turn it off.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll test and tell you it worked

Comment: @Paulw11 `startUpdatingLocation` will update location when app is killed/suspensed right ?

Comment: Do you know if the mobile network in Brazil is using GMS or UTMS?

Comment: @shallowThought is UTMS

Answer (score 0):

In plist addd these

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

[image]

```
  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()  // Add this Code 
  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: Have you added above code before locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

Comment: When the application opens, I use locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization

Comment: Also use this locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization than checked your app

Comment: Sorry, I said `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, but I'm using `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your *AppDelegate* **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
  //location manager
  locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  locationManager.delegate = self
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
  locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Call locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() in your first screen **viewDidLoad()** (or Anywhere not in **didEnterBackground**)